# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. when Migration database on .Net 6.0

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, .net-6.0, database-migration

When I try to add a migration and then do `update-database`, this error occurs:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

I am using Visual Studio 2022,.Net 6.0, and SQL Server 2022 with SSMS 19.

Also, I put the server authentication as "SQL server and Windows authentication mode".

My connection string is:

```
Server=DESKTOP-UQCH6NV;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/certificate-chain-not-trusted?tabs=ole-db-driver-19